# what we do wtih tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(self.a)[0], dtype=tf.int32), self.a], axis=1)

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is done with this command? What does `tf.stack` stands for what?

```
tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(self.a)[0], dtype=tf.int32), self.a], axis=1)
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack)? According to it, tf.stack "Stacks a list of rank-R tensors into one rank-(R+1) tensor."

Comment: Thanks I saw this before but I did not understand what is its meaninng? if a is one dimension then what is meaning of tf.stack[tf.range?]

Comment: Ok, so instead of asking 'What does tf.stack do?', ask "What does tf.stack do? I read that it "Stacks a list of rank-R tensors into one rank-(R+1) tensor.", but I don't understand the term X and Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, I try the NumPy equivalents to the TensorFlow functions when I'm working things out.  Initially, the TensorFlow API had some quirky differences to the NumPy API, but enough users want the two packages to behave the same that TensorFlow is making changes.

You say that the array `self.a` is guaranteed to be 1D.  All right then:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(-9,9,(10,))
print(arr)
result = np.stack([np.arange(np.shape(arr)[0], dtype=np.int32), arr], axis=1)
print(result)
```

Here's a sample output:

```
array([-5,  1,  0, -3, -9, -8,  3, -1,  0, -2])

array([[ 0, -5],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 2,  0],
       [ 3, -3],
       [ 4, -9],
       [ 5, -8],
       [ 6,  3],
       [ 7, -1],
       [ 8,  0],
       [ 9, -2]])
```

So, it looks like the original 1D array is enlarged into a 2D array with a numerical index in the 0th column.